# Unable to login using SQL Developer?

Tags: database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Recently I installed Oracle 12c and using the below commands in sqlplus I created a user, set the password and grant connection privileges. I can successfuly login with PYTHON user using sqlplus and create tables.

```
ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true; 
CREATE USER PYTHON IDENTIFIED BY “1234”;
GRANT CONNECT TO PYTHON;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO PYTHON;
```

BUT when I try to login with he same credentials using SQL Developer it shows me the below error
ORA-12505 , TNS listener does not currently know of SID given in connector description

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 12c XE..only 11g and 18c XE.

So your service name is wrong.

Try orcl

Or check your logs for the database service name

Comment: Excellent, let is know how it's going..if you have any questions about the tool, drop me a line